# Use Arduino shields with the Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, arduino

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 and a bunch of old Arduino shields. I am switching a project from the Arduino to the Raspberry Pi 2, and I would not like to buy a lot of new components. I have limited space, so I cannot attach the shields to a breadboard and then connect it to the pi. I need them to be able to attach on top of the pi.

Is there any way to easily use my Arduino shields with my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Adafruit (and perhaps other companies) make cheap [Pi HAT perma-prototype boards](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2310) you could use to make your own adapter; obviously this is going to add 1/4"-1/2" in height and have some limitations, but you should be able to fit, e.g., at least of couple of level shifters on there.  The awkward part is pairing it with the shields you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are bridges that do this available. Arduberry springs to mind. Try googling for "rpi arduino shields" and you will get some options. Don't count on all shields to be supported, though.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure about the software side of things (maybe the same for SPI and I2C), but whatever you do, make ***SURE*** you use 3.3v-5v logic converters. If that isn't an option to you, though, you might want to consider plugging the Arduino into a USB port on the RPi and communicating serially between the two, using the Arduino to drive the shields and the RPi to do the processing.

Comment: That's what I have been doing so far(about the serial communication), but it's too bulky

Comment: Also, I need the shield to stack well on the pi